# In google analytics should I add or remove trailing slashes?

Tags: google-analytics

I am developing a set of standard filters to deploy for every client I have that needs Google Analytics support. One of those filters is to add a trailing slash (i.e., "/" to the end of each URL that doesn't include query parameters).

While I am able to understand the advanced filters using regular expressions to accomplish this, I am not sure which is the right way to go.

I have seen some articles that say you should remove this just to help consolidate URLs and others that say you should have the trailing slash to help GA understand the directory hierarchy of your site.

Which is it?

Best,

Kevin

Comment: Google Analytics does not care (you should use a unified format for the sake of the people who read the reports, though). It used to be that you should use trailing slashes for performance reasons (lest you force your server to do an internal redirect to actually find the content) but I have no idea if that still matters. Also having urls that work with and without trailing slashes used to bring a small SEO penalty (since two urls for one resource count as duplicate content), bit I don't know if that still applies plus it's not relevant for the reports.

Comment: Great answer, @EikePierstorff. Just want to add that if the canonical tags are correctly set up, for example for the link with the `/`, then even if someone entered the link without the `/`, Google will give SEO credit to the one with the `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I really appreciate it. This might be a little off topic, but I have a follow on question about the use of canonical URLs and their impact on SEO. I know they are important, and I understand in general what they are, but I am more of an analytics and conversion optimization wonk vs. an SEO engineer. Do you have a resource you would recommend for best practices around implementing canonical URLs at the server level in a way that helps with SEO and prevents the need for these URLs?